# files copy and paste absolute file paths

Tags: files

I'm currently working with an updated Elementary OS 5.1.2 Hera". After some of the last updates the system started to change the behavior when I copy and paste files/folders from the file browser (I am suing the default  `io.elementary.files`).

Before the change: after selection of a file/folder, I used to to copy with `CTRL-C`, then going into a text editor or the terminal with `CTRL-V` I just pasted the full (absolute) file path or directory eg:

`/home/user/bla/bla/filename.ext`

Recently this wonderful behavior changed, in the sense that when I do CTRL-V in editors/terminal it pastes

`file:///home/user/bla/bla/filename.ext`

Now it is so annoying to go back and forth and delete `file://` from the filepath.

Is there any way to get back to the good old behavior?

Comment: It seems that this issue may be a general issue, see this: [https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/nautilus/issues/634](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/nautilus/issues/634), and this [https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nautilus/+bug/1826266](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nautilus/+bug/1826266). Although I am not sure how much eOS gets from other stuff like nautilus and gnome.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't done any setting, but after last update today the issue disappeared.

Therefore, now copying a file into `Files` and pasting into terminal/text editor does the right this, e.g. it pastes

`/home/user/bla/bla/filename.ext`

I wonder where this has been fixed.

Answer (score 0):

This behavior has been changed.
Now it just copies and pastes whatever path you copy directly. I don’t believe it’s a setting that you can change, but make sure your eOS install is on the latest version with all of the updates.